# How to choose the environment in a python chunk in rmarkdown

Tags: python, r-markdown, reticulate

I try to get familiar with python in R.
I made it work using reticulate along the following lines:

```
library(reticulate)
py_install("pandas")
```

Then I can always get back to the enviroment where I installed that to using

```
use_condaenv("r-reticulate")
```

How can I use this in a python chunk of the following form

````
```{python}
import pandas as pd
```
````

pandas can be found in the first version above (using reticulate) but not in the version with the python chunk. How can I tell it to use the "r-reticulate" environment? Setting it in an R set-up chunk in the following form does not work for me

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(reticulate)
use_condaenv("r-reticulate")
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, it was fixed by setting the `required` keyword to `TRUE`.

`use_condaenv(condaenv='env-name', required = TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you! I think now I passed the first issue but got stock somewhere else :) But the environment looks fine now. Thank you!